# I want to make an advertising html code faster

Tags: android, html, css, performance, blogs

I do articles on blogs, but I want to know if this code can be simplified so that the page is faster without affecting other things

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- easd descargas texto -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxx" data-ad-format="link" data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {...});`, which will wait for the HTML to load before executing that piece of JS.

There still might be a bit of lag while the advertisements load, but there's not much you can do as that depends on the advertisement. You're letting other code run on your site, so you have no control over what it is, only when it is loaded.